# Find a mail with a status and compare date scheduled with now (MONGO/PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a little problem to send a mail. I searching to send many mails come from my db with 2 conditons :

- Mail with status 'TO_SEND.
- Mail with a date scheduled.

These two conditions do run in the find request like this :

```
$mails = $database->mails->find(['status' => 'TO_SEND', ['date_scheduled' => ['$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime()]]]);
```

Find mails with the status is good, but when i'm adding scheduled condition i have this message  :

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime::__construct() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Users/Developpeur/cron/cron_mail.php:22
Stack trace:

## 0 /Users/Developpeur/cron/cron_mail.php(22): MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime->__construct()

## 1 {main}

thrown in **/Users/Developpeur/cron/cron_mail.php** on line **22**

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The UTCDateTime() constructor expects a single parameter (the number of milliseconds since epoch). I'm no PHP expert, but you should be able to pass `time() * 1000` as the parameter to create a MongoDB UTCDateTime for the current date/time. Your request would look like this:

```
$mails = $database->mails->find(['status' => 'TO_SEND', ['date_scheduled' => ['$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(time() * 1000)]]]);
```

Comment: Thak's Jerod , my error is fadded away! but my mail are not send... ^^

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get past the error from the datetime condition! Your issue with sending the email is a separate one and is probably worth asking a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do you think MongoDB can't compare two dates?

My query tries to compare a new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(time() * 1000) with an isoDate stored in my collection : 

"date_scheduled" : ISODate("2016-07-10T11:18:57.000+0000")"

Comment: Are the proper items being returned from the database? Meaning those mail items with status 'TO_SEND' and whose DateTime is greater than the current time (meaning messages to be sent in the future).